# How to set a background image of a UIImageView controller objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

My comsci class is working on an app that will display maps of our school depending on the day and the floor. We can't get the segue to work going from the SecondTableViewController to the MapViewController because, we believe, the background image (the maps) isn't properly set.

SecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *daysName;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *floorName;

@end
```

SecondViewController.m

```
#import "SecondTableViewController.h"
#import "MapViewController.h"

@interface SecondTableViewController ()


@end

@implementation SecondTableViewController {



    NSArray *ADay;
    NSArray *BDay;
    NSArray *CDay;
    NSArray *DDay;
    NSArray *EDay;
    NSArray *FDay;
    NSArray *GDay;
    NSArray *HDay;


}

/*-(void)configureWithImage:(UIImage *)paramImage
{
    self.capturedImage = paramImage;
}*/

-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self)
    {
        //custom initalization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ADay = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1stFloor",@"2ndFloor", @"3rdFloor", nil];
    BDay = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1stFloor",@"2ndFloor", @"3rdFloor", nil];
    CDay = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1stFloor",@"2ndFloor", @"3rdFloor", nil];
    DDay = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1stFloor",@"2ndFloor", @"3rdFloor", nil];
    EDay = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1stFloor",@"2ndFloor", @"3rdFloor", nil];
    FDay = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1stFloor",@"2ndFloor", @"3rdFloor", nil];
    GDay = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1stFloor",@"2ndFloor", @"3rdFloor", nil];
    HDay = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1stFloor",@"2ndFloor", @"3rdFloor", nil];

    //self.backImageView.image = self.capturedImage;


}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if ([_daysName isEqualToString:@"ADay"])
    {
        return [ADay count];
    }
    else if ([_daysName isEqualToString:@"BDay"])
    {
        return [BDay count];
    }

    else if ([_daysName isEqualToString:@"CDay"])
    {
        return [CDay count];
    }
    else if ([_daysName isEqualToString:@"DDay"])
    {
        return [DDay count];
    }
    else if ([_daysName isEqualToString:@"EDay"])
    {
        return [EDay count];
    }
    else if ([_daysName isEqualToString:@"FDay"])
    {
        return [FDay count];
    }
    else if ([_daysName isEqualToString:@"GDay"])
    {
        return [GDay count];
    }
    else if ([_daysName isEqualToString:@"HDay"])
    {
        return [HDay count];
    }
    return 0;
}

- (UIImage *)cellBackgroundForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath //:(NSString *)floorName
{
   // NSInteger rowCount = [self tableView:[self tableView] numberOfRowsInSection:0];
    NSInteger rowIndex = indexPath.row;
    UIImage *background = nil;

    return background;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Floors2Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    if ([_daysName isEqualToString:@"ADay"]) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [ADay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    else if ([_daysName isEqualToString:@"BDay"]) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [BDay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else if ([_daysName isEqualToString:@"CDay"]) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [CDay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else if ([_daysName isEqualToString:@"DDay"]) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [DDay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else if ([_daysName isEqualToString:@"EDay"]) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [EDay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else if ([_daysName isEqualToString:@"FDay"]) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [FDay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else if ([_daysName isEqualToString:@"GDay"]) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [GDay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else if ([_daysName isEqualToString:@"HDay"]) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [HDay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    // Assign our own background image for the cell
    UIImage *background = [self cellBackgroundForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *cellBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:background];
    cellBackgroundView.image = background;
    cell.backgroundView = cellBackgroundView;

    return cell;
}



#pragma mark - Navigation
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showFloorDetail"]) {
        NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1stFloor",@"2ndFloor", @"3rdFloor", nil];

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        MapViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        UIImage *Background;

        if ([_daysName isEqual:@"ADay" ]) {
            if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"2ndFloor"]) {
                Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"A2 copy.JPEG"];
            }

            if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"3rdFloor"]) {
                Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"A3 copy.png"];
            }
            //background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1stFloor"];
        }

        else if ([_daysName isEqual:@"BDay" ]) {
            if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"2ndFloor"]) {
                Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"B2 copy.png"];
            }

            if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"3rdFloor"]) {
                Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"B3 copy.JPEG"];
            }
        }

        else if ([_daysName isEqual:@"CDay" ]){

            if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"2ndFloor"]) {
                Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"C2 copy.JPEG"];
            }

            if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"3rdFloor"]) {
                Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"C3 copy.JPEG"];
            }
        }

        else if ([_daysName isEqual:@"DDay" ]) {
            if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"2ndFloor"]) {
                Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"D2 copy.JPEG"];
            }

            if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"3rdFloor"]) {
                Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"D3 copy.JPEG"];
            }
        }

        else if ([_daysName isEqual:@"EDay" ]) {
            if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"2ndFloor"]) {
                Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"E2 copy.JPEG"];
            }

            if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"3rdFloor"]) {
                Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"E3 copy.JPEG"];
            }
        }

        else if ([_daysName isEqual:@"FDay" ]) {
            if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"2ndFloor"]) {
                Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"F2 copy.JPEG"];
            }

            if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"3rdFloor"]) {
                Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"F3 copy.JPEG"];
            }
        }

        else if ([_daysName isEqual:@"GDay" ]) {
            if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"2ndFloor"]) {
                Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"G2 copy.JPEG"];
            }

            if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"3rdFloor"]) {
                Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"G3 copy.JPEG"];
            }
        }

        else {
            if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"2ndFloor"]) {
                Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"H2 copy.JPEG"];
            }

            if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"3rdFloor"]) {
                Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"H3 copy.JPEG"];
            }
        }

        [destViewController configureWithImage:Background];
        destViewController.floorName = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        self.floorName = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        destViewController.title = destViewController.floorName;
    }
}

@end
```

Then it leads to MapViewController, which is a UIImageView

MapViewController.h

```
        #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
//#import "SecondTableViewController.m"

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString *floorName;
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString *daysName;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *background;

@end
```

MapViewController.m

```
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import "SecondTableViewController.h"

@interface MapViewController ()

-(void)configureWithImage:(UIImage *)paramImage;

@end

@implementation MapViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.daysName = _daysName;


// Assign our own background image for the cell
   UIImage *Background;

    if ([_daysName isEqual:@"ADay" ]) {
        if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"2ndFloor"]) {
            Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"A2 copy.JPEG"];
        }

        if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"3rdFloor"]) {
            Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"A3 copy.png"];
        }
        //background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1stFloor"];
    }

    else if ([_daysName isEqual:@"BDay" ]) {
        if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"2ndFloor"]) {
            Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"B2 copy.png"];
        }

        if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"3rdFloor"]) {
            Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"B3 copy.JPEG"];
        }
    }

    else if ([_daysName isEqual:@"CDay" ]){

        if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"2ndFloor"]) {
            Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"C2 copy.JPEG"];
        }

        if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"3rdFloor"]) {
            Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"C3 copy.JPEG"];
        }
    }

    else if ([_daysName isEqual:@"DDay" ]) {
        if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"2ndFloor"]) {
            Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"D2 copy.JPEG"];
        }

        if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"3rdFloor"]) {
            Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"D3 copy.JPEG"];
        }
    }

    else if ([_daysName isEqual:@"EDay" ]) {
        if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"2ndFloor"]) {
            Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"E2 copy.JPEG"];
        }

        if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"3rdFloor"]) {
            Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"E3 copy.JPEG"];
        }
    }

    else if ([_daysName isEqual:@"FDay" ]) {
        if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"2ndFloor"]) {
            Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"F2 copy.JPEG"];
        }

        if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"3rdFloor"]) {
            Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"F3 copy.JPEG"];
        }
    }

    else if ([_daysName isEqual:@"GDay" ]) {
        if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"2ndFloor"]) {
            Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"G2 copy.JPEG"];
        }

        if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"3rdFloor"]) {
            Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"G3 copy.JPEG"];
        }
    }

    else {
        if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"2ndFloor"]) {
            Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"H2 copy.JPEG"];
        }

        if ([_floorName  isEqual: @"3rdFloor"]) {
            Background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"H3 copy.JPEG"];
        }
    }


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

We don't know why the segue doesn't work and why we can't figure out how to set the background of MapViewController.

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: The phrase "doesn't work" communicates nothing. Explain.

Comment: All that code, and no implementation of the only method that matters on the Map VC: `configureWithImage:`

Comment: UIImageView controller?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to move the method declaration to the "MapViewController.h" in order for it to be accessible from the first viewController. :

```
//MapViewController.h
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController
   -(void)configureWithImage:(UIImage *)paramImage;
@end
```

Second, you should call the segue in the originating view controller:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showFloorDetail" sender:self];
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments, there is not implementation of  your configureWithImage method in the MapViewController.m

```
-(void)configureWithImage:(UIImage *)paramImage {
    // Process your image here
    [yourImageView setImage:paramImage];
}
```

Few more comments: MapViewController is not an UIImageView. The way it is set in your code, you are subclassing UIViewController. Also, please name variables starting with lower case letters (as per Apple convention) . Only classes should be named with  the first letter in upper case.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but everything you said I have done.  If you have any other ideas as to why it doesn't work that would be really helpful! It's in xcode.

Comment: Can you tell us more about why it doesn't work? Error message? NSlog outputs?